Twilio Studio - Collecting call handling information
I've completed the development of my IVR using the Twilio platform. Now I have a question: I'm not interested in using Flex to collect this information. Is there any way to collect call duration, available agents, completed calls, and other information using Studio?

Unfortunately, collecting call duration, available agents, completed calls, and other detailed information directly through Twilio Studio is not supported. However, you can achieve this by utilizing Twilio's APIs such as the Programmable Voice API to gather the specific call data you require. Here is an example of how you can retrieve call logs using Twilio's Programmable Voice API
I hope this helps in achieving the desired functionality for your IVR solution.
